# Error unable to get worksheet function RSq an Intercept but no issues with LINEST ? why ? and how to fix?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub S_Reg_Matrixes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i, j As Long
Dim Pente() As Double
Dim vlive As Range
Dim rmat As Range
Dim dmat As Range
Dim betamat As Range
Dim alphamat As Range
Dim gammamat As Range
Dim lout As Range
Dim VV As Range
Dim Rb As Workbook
Set Rb = Workbooks("Tools.xlsm")
Dim RMW As Workbook
Set RMW = Workbooks("REG_MATRIXES.xlsm")

' Defining Ranges:
Rb.Activate
Set vlive = Rb.Worksheets("STATISTICS").Range("StatLiveVol")
RMW.Activate
Set rmat = Worksheets("SLOPE").Range("SRMatrix")
Set dmat = Worksheets("SLOPE").Range("SDistMatrix")
Set betamat = Worksheets("SLOPE").Range("AE6:AO19")
Set alphamat = Worksheets("SLOPE").Range("AP6:AZ19")
Set gammamat = RMW.Worksheets("SLOPE").Range("BA6:BK19")
Set lout = Worksheets("SLOPE").Range("BL6:BV19")
Set VV = Worksheets("SLOPE").Range("SVarVol")

'Calculate and Fill R^2 Matrix as well as get dist variables


Dim out1() As Double
    For i = 1 To 14
        For j = 1 To 11
            out1 = OutStat(bucket(vlive(i, j)), Range("SRegScale"))
            'MsgBox (out1(UBound(out1) - LBound(out1)) + 1)
            Pente = slope(bucket(vlive(i, j)), Range("SRegScale"))

            VV(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Var_P(out1)
            Call NewScatter_Eliot(Pente, out1)
            rmat(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.RSq(out1, Pente) ' Is throwing Error
            betamat(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(out1, Pente)
            alphamat(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Intercept(out1, Pente) ' Is throwing Error
            gammamat(i, j) = Pente(UBound(Pente) - LBound(Pente) + 1)
            lout(i, j) = out1(UBound(out1) - LBound(out1) + 1)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am working on a VBA Macro where I regress many times . I don't know why I am getting this error when it is totally okay with Lin Est ?? and I need to fix this error. Pente is an array and out1 too, both have the same length too.

Comment: Can you point out which line throws the error? Also, rather than activating the workbooks, try and use the workbook objects you already have. It's more efficient and guarantees that you are always interacting with correct workbook

Comment: You have it now commented. Yes maybe you're right but it's not that the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RSq` might experience some calculation error, such as a division by zero.

To check that and have your code continue running, try using `Application` instead:

```
rmat(i, j) = Application.RSq(out1, Pente)`
'            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After that, verify in the worksheet that you have error results, i.e. `#DIV/0!`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that I the function slope was regressing something on 0 for the first line and so this first row of 0 was giving the error.